# Unable to extract bz2 reddit monthly comments file Mac

Tags: macos, bz2

Am not able to extract monthly `redit` comment files downloaded in `bz2` format on my computer.

For example, When i extract **`RC_2005-12.bz2`** using The Unarchiver, there is a **`RC_2005-12`** file extracted without any extension. I am not able to open that **`RC_2005-12`** file .

Am using Mac with Sierra. Am downloading files from here http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Open Finder. Tap once (very gently) on the file with the left mouse button. Press SPACE. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the [RC_2005-12.bz2](http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/RC_2005-12.bz2) file from http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/, and then in my Download folder in Finder, double-click it.

It extracted using the macOS default Archive Utility.

The extracted file, RC_2005-12, is a plan text document and when doubling-clicking it, it open in TextEdit.

If that doesn't work for you, I'd try downloading the file again.

Comment: Thank You! yes i am able to extract the text doc.